# Slackware boot error after fresh install

Tags: ubuntu, grub, dual-boot, slackware

I'm currently running Ubuntu and Slackware on my system. After just installing Slackware, with everything appearing to work fine, I boot into GRUB only to see an "error: no such disk" or something of another when I try to load Slackware. Does anyone know why this is the case?

**update**

I first installed Slackware with a full install on one of my partitions, a swap included. During this time I chose *not* to install LILO. After this, I then proceeded to install Ubuntu just so I could have something which would work when I needed it to. This is when I installed GRUB2, and when Slackware just refused to work.

Should I reinstall it with LILO this time? If I do this, will it scrap my Ubuntu or should I still be able to use it?

**update 2**

I think this is the problem:

```
menuentry "Slackware Linux (Slackware 13.37.0) (on /dev/sda8)" --class gnu-linux --class g      nu --class os {
       insmod part_gpt
       insmod ext2
       set root='(/dev/sda,gpt8)'
       search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 89ba52ea-8afa-4d93-adac-e4a9258a2aae
       linux /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda8
  }
```

I don't know much about grub.cfg, but from it seems like (and from what I've been reading of the ubuntu documentation), this appears to be correct. I think the uuid isn't being found, however. Should I replace the uuid with the partition it's located on?

Comment: Grub2 or legacy? Can you provide some details on how you added Slackware to the grub menu?

Comment: Create a custom menu entry in Grub2 for Slackware: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Creating_the_Custom_Menu

Comment: There already is a menu entry for Slackware though. Are you saying that a custom menu entry might actually make it work, as opposed to the one that is already there?

Answer (score 1):

If Slackware is on `sda8`, then your `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file should look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0

menuentry "Slackware" {
set root=(hd0,8)
linux /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda8 ro quiet
}
```

You can use UUIDs, which would then look something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0

menuentry "Slackware"{
set root=(hd0,8)
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set cf984a2a-8892-4d79-a0dc-2fc81ee04edb
linux /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/disk/by-uuid/cf984a2a-8892-4d79-a0dc-2fc81ee04edb ro vga=872
}
```

Make sure that you run `update-grub` as root to apply the changes...